# Installing Ubuntu in a Acer E1 with UEFI

Tags: uefi, system-installation

I have a cheap $300 Acer E1 series laptop with UEFI and Windows 8. Btw, the only "BIOS" in the boot menu is UEFI. I want to wipe windows 8 COMPLETELY off the hdd and replace it with Ubuntu or Fedora. I'll try Ubuntu first even though I heard that Fedora has better support for all that UEFI junk. I wrote the 64 bit ubuntu ISO to USB (made with unetbootin) and DVD so that I could install it on my laptop.

First, I disabled the UEFI. When I boot with a live USB or DVD of Ubuntu, I get a black screen with 3 options - Install, Try, Check something. When I choose install, I get a black screen. It stays there forever. How do I even know that I can install ubuntu on this system? This laptop does not come with a dvd/cd drive. I am using an external. Doesn't matter. I returned it all.

Comment: take a look at partitioning scheme https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace also might wanna read an article posted by [Rod Smith](http://askubuntu.com/questions/423308/startup-problem-with-ubuntu-12-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment547552_423308)

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @RodSmith - Sorry, but that link did not help me. Is there someone I can pay to do this ? I enabled Secure boot as per the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18F3CZveMwg&feature=youtu.be . At least my drive was making noises and then the screen went black again.

Comment: Thanks karel. I am trying the ubuntu 12.04 mini cd instead. I am not sure though. I am thinking of returning my laptop and buying a new non UEFI laptop. Just because microsoft can't program a secure OS, I have to suffer.

Comment: I saw one setting in the bios which says - "select an uefi file as trusted for executing" Perhaps I could get some "unbuntu file" and add it there ?

Comment: 1) I recommended that you post a comment to @RodSmith and ask him about `select an uefi file as trusted for executing`. He wrote a book about stuff like that. 2) I noticed that your question got stuck in the review queue because someone who hasn't had his coffee thinks that it's a duplicate of the other one. So change the wording to make it not look like a duplicate, especially the wording of the title. 3) The new Asus laptops have almost the same specs as yours and they are shipped with no OS preinstalled.

Comment: Have you seen? http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069

Comment: OP gave up. http://askubuntu.com/a/424866/44179

Answer (score 2):

> Btw, the only "BIOS" in the boot menu is UEFI.

Are you **absolutly sure** that you can **not change the bootmode** in your Acer E1 Series **BIOS ?**
I am asking you that because i bought an **Acer E1-530** too, and i have a BIOS on it where **im able to switch bootmode** from UEFI to standard. So you may want to doublecheck on this and saving time and money.

Did you try to press **F2** or DEL **while Booting** ?

Ps: I do answer here because i **CAN NOT COMMENT** yet.

Ps²: @please click this

[image: InsydeH20 Acer BIOS]

Comment: Can you please give me the full model number ? There are different models in the E1 series. Mine had ONLY uefi - 100% sure about that. I don't remember the exact model number though. It was an E1 series for sure. I might just buy your model if I get enough proof that it is easy. Thanks.

Comment: @please click this : Sure,its an : **Acer Aspire E1-530-21174G50Mnkk NX.MEQEG.004 Linux**, Model No.: **Z5WE1**. But it may be worth mentioning that the built in card reader is not working with Linux actually. Everything else is just fine. **PS:** I'm not saying that it is easy to install UEFI here, i was just trying to help by explaining that UEFI can easiely be disabled.**Bst.rgrds.**

Comment: How much time did it take for you to install unbuntu on your laptop ? I am getting desperate to finish off the ubuntu project now. I have searched so many online and offline stores with a non-uefi laptop with no success.

Comment: Now, I am trying to move HDD of my old non UEFI laptop to a new expensive laptop and put ubuntu on oldy. Here is the question - http://superuser.com/questions/723439/moving-windows-oem-hard-drive-to-new-laptop

Comment: @pleaseclickthis: The ubuntu install just took the regulary time to install. Maybe around 15 to 20 Minutes. There were no extra work to do, everything ran out of the box. Except, as i mentioned before, the sd-card reader.

Answer (score 1):

This not much of an answer - I fail and I give up. I am returning my laptop. I'll pay more and get some system where it will be easy to install linux.

There are a so many tutorials on this and not one has helped me. Reminds me of the 2 days I spent in getting wifi to work in ubuntu 11, on a expensive laptop with mainstream hardware.

Comment: Good luck.  UEFI can be a headache.

Comment: @belacqua - yes. I wasted 10 hours and made zero progress. 10 hours of work * 20 per hour = $200. Add that to the laptop budget and get some win 7 system.

Comment: Err... Ubuntu 11 is old and wont work at all in UEFI. You need 12.04 64-bit or newer

Comment: @Braiam - I was not trying u11 with uefi. that was an old story. I tried u12.04 64 bit with uefi  and failed. the laptop has been returned.